# Не работает js в модальном окне

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не работает проверка заполнения пустых полей в модальном окне `bootstrap`?

Вот код формы:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="leadModal">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-body">
             <form action="" method="post" id="contact2">
                <table  border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
                   <tr>
                      <td><label>Тема</label><input type="text" value="Заказ"/><div></div></td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                     <td><input id="submit2" type="submit" value="Отправить"/><div></div></td>
                   </tr>
                </table>
             </form>
          </div><!-- /.modal-body -->
       </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

JS:

```
$('#contact2').submit(function(){
  var errors=false;
  $(this).find('div').empty();
  $(this).find('input, textarea').each(function(){
    if($.trim($(this).val())==''){
      errors=true;$(this).next().text('Заполните пожалуйста поле: '+$(this).prev().text());
    }
  });
  if(!errors){
    var data=$('#contact2').serialize();
    $.ajax({
      url:'',
      type:'POST',
      data:data,
      beforeSend:function(){
        $('#submit2').next().text('Отправляю...');
      },
      success:function(res){
        if(res==1){
          $('#contact2').find('input:not(#submit2), textarea').val('');
          $('#submit2').next().empty();alert('Заказ успешно отправлен. О наличии товара мы сообщим Вам на почту');
        }else{
          $('#submit2').next().empty();alert('Ошибка отправки');
        }
      },
      error:function(){
        alert('Ошибка!');
      }
    });
  }
  return false;
});
```

Если вставлять форму не в модальное окно, а просто на страницу сайту, то все отлично работает, показывает какие поля не заполнены.

Comment: все работает - http://jsbin.com/kequqotazi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Jean-Claude у меня не работает! Перезагружает страницу заново.

Comment: @димончег по моей ссылке не работает? У меня работает.

Comment: @Jean-Claude по твоей работает, у меня просто еще код был структуры модального окна, я не весь выложил, вот поэтому там что-то не так видимо, буду разбираться. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работает
В пятой строке поставьте сравнение ===

```js
$('#contact2').submit(function(){
  var errors=false;
  $(this).find('div').empty();
  $(this).find('input, textarea').each(function(){
    if($.trim($(this).val())===''){
      errors=true;$(this).next().text('Заполните пожалуйста поле: '+$(this).prev().text());
    }
  });
  if(!errors){
    var data=$('#contact2').serialize();
    $.ajax({
      url:'',
      type:'POST',
      data:data,
      beforeSend:function(){
        $('#submit2').next().text('Отправляю...');
      },
      success:function(res){
        if(res==1){
          $('#contact2').find('input:not(#submit2), textarea').val('');
          $('#submit2').next().empty();alert('Заказ успешно отправлен. О наличии товара мы сообщим Вам на почту');
        }else{
          $('#submit2').next().empty();alert('Ошибка отправки');
        }
      },
      error:function(){
        alert('Ошибка!');
      }
    });
  }
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Посмотреть демо
      </button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Название модали</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       
        
        
        
        <form action="" method="post" id="contact2">
                <table  border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
                   <tr>
                      <td><label>Тема</label><input type="text" value="Заказ"/><div></div></td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                     <td><input id="submit2" type="submit" value="Отправить"/><div></div></td>
                   </tr>
                </table>
             </form>
        
        
        
        
        
        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить изменения</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Разобрался почему не работает.

У меня форма в форме, поэтому не работает, как можно это исправить?
`<form action="" method="post" id="contact"> <form action="" method="post" id="contact2"> </form></form>`

Comment: @Дмитрий убрать форму из формы

Comment: Извиняюсь, я сам ошибся, конечно, форма в форме не должна быть, я не то немножко скинул... сейчас исправлю выше код